# Error : Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object when I try Closure based middleware directly in controller's constructor. Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel 5.2. In the constructor

```
public function __construct(){     
    $this->data['user'] =  Auth::guard('customer')->user();        
    $this->middleware('customer');
}
```

So, I can use the "$this->data['user']" anywhere in the controller.

But In Laravel 5.3 or above we can't access the authenticated user in the constructor. And when I try to use Closure based middleware in the constructor.

```
public function __construct(){    
    $this->data['user'] =  Auth::guard('customer')->user();
    $this->middleware('customer');
}
```

Then I receive the error:

> ErrorException Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object
>   http://localhost/dhruv/intranet-v6.0/public/profile

Comment: the middleware guard `customer` is present on your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('customer');
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->data['user'] = Auth::guard('customer')->user();

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```